# How to update cosmos db document using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I want to update document in cosmos DB if the file name already exists. For that, I passed a query which will bring result and I want to update that result. I want to set the modified date to it. If it's new creating one if it is already there add the modified date to it.
I am facing the problem updating it which will come in else part.
Here is my code snippet:

```
        Class1 obj = new Class1()
        {
            BlobPath = "/container",
            size = (int)myBlob.Length,
            Name = name,
            CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()

        };
        string obj1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Class1>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testDb", "testDocumentCollection"))
           .Where(jo => jo.Name.Equals(name))
            .AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();


        if (query == null)
        {

            var document1 = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(
                            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testDb", "testDocumentCollection"),
                            obj);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To update a document you have to use the Upsert-Method:
[DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.upsertdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet)

This blog entry has some details about it:
[DocumentDB: To create, or not to create, that is the question](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/documentdb-adds-upsert/)

Comment: upsert would be the way to do it

Comment: I used upsert but instead of updating the existing file, it creates a new one

Comment: @Aman Does your JSON-Document contain the id of the existing document? 
 var docSpec = new { id = "document id", foo = "bar" };

Comment: But `name` is not `id`. Do your duplicate entries in the CosmosDB have the same `id`?